# Find $x^{10}y^6z^{-21}$ in $(3x^2 -5y^{\frac{1}{2}} + z^{-3})^{24}$ with Binomial theorem.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-theorem

Find $x^{10}y^6z^{-21}$ and $x^{16}y^4z^{-18}$ in $(3x^2 -5y^{\frac{1}{2}} + z^{-3})^{24}$ with Binomial theorem.

Well, I believe I found $x^{10}y^6z^{-21}$ and $x^{16}y^4z^{-18}$ .

But, I'm a bit hesitated about the solution, because I didn't use the fact: $i+j+k = 24$ and I believe I have to use it.  What do you guys think? Here's my solution:
[image]

Comment: The very last one with $8!8!6!$ can't be right, I think that part is a trick question...

Comment: @abiessu Exactly. I'm trying to find the problem in the second one. I just noticed that the first one's $i+j+k=24$ is good.

Comment: @abiessu: So, I'll just write that it doesn't have a solution?

Comment: Yes, the second part doesn't actually exist within the trinomial expansion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is also convenient to use the *[coefficient of](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9402216)* operator $[x^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^n$ in an algebraic expression.

> Instead of using the multinomial version we could also successively apply the binomial theorem. We obtain
>
> \begin{align*}
> [x^{10}&y^6z^{-21}](3x^2-5y^{\frac{1}{2}}+z^{-3})^{24}\tag{1}\\
> &=[x^{10}y^6z^{-21}]\sum_{k=0}^{24}\binom{24}{k}3^kx^{2k}(-5y^{\frac{1}{2}}+z^{-3})^{24-k}\tag{2}\\
> &=3^5\binom{24}{5}[y^6z^{-21}](-5y^{\frac{1}{2}}+z^{-3})^{19}\\
> &=3^5\binom{24}{5}[y^6z^{-21}]\sum_{k=0}^{19}\binom{19}{k}(-5)^ky^{\frac{1}{2}k}z^{-3(19-k)}\tag{3}\\
> &=3^5(-5)^{12}\binom{24}{5}\binom{19}{12}\\
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2) we select $k=5$ in order to obtain the coefficient of $[x^{10}]$.
- In (3) we select $k=12$ in order to obtain the coefficient of $[y^{6}]$ as well as $[z^{-21}]$.

> *Note:* If we consider a summand $$[x^{10}y^6z^{-21}]a_{ijk}x^{2i}y^{\frac{1}{2}j}z^{-3k}$$ of the trinomial (1) with coefficient $a_{ijk}$, the following equations have to be fulfilled in order to find a possible solution
>   \begin{align*}
> i+j+k&=24\\
> 2i&=10\\
> \frac{1}{2}j&=6\\
> -3k&=-21
> \end{align*}
>
> The last three equations give $i=5,j=12$ and $k=7$ fulfilling $i+j+k=24$.

---

> We start (as we could always do) the second example with a plausibility check regarding the exponents
>
> \begin{align*}
> [x^{16}&y^4z^{-18}](3x^2-5y^{\frac{1}{2}}+z^{-3})^{24}
> \end{align*}
>
> We get the following equations
>
> \begin{align*}
> i+j+k&=24\\
> 2i&=16\\
> \frac{1}{2}j&=4\\
> -3k&=-18
> \end{align*}
>
> The last three equations give $i=8,j=8$ and $k=6$ *not* fulfilling $i+j+k=24$.
>
> We conclude
>   \begin{align*}
> [x^{16}&y^4z^{-18}](3x^2-5y^{\frac{1}{2}}+z^{-3})^{24}=0
> \end{align*}